# Passing variable parameters to a function

Tags: c

I have a C function that takes a custom structure and an variable amount of arguments with different types(ints/strings/other custom structures...). Because of the structure, the function is able determine of what type each argument is, in order to process it.

```
void doStuff(MyStruct *S,...){ <function code> }
```

Now i need another function that can pass an 'n' number of constant arguments to "doStuff". I.e. something like this:

```
void useDoStuff(Mystruct *S, int n){ //lets say n=4
    va_list arguments;
    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
       if(i%2) arguments.add(6);   //example condition for the arguments
       else arguments.add("Hello");
    }
    doStuff(S, arguments); // doStuff(S, "Hello", 6, "Hello", 6);
}
```

Naturally this wont work, because va_list can't be used like this(used it only to roughly 'visualize' what is needed). Unfortunately neither the structure nor 'doStuff' function can be changed and I need to find a workaround. Does such workaround exist?

Comment: This isn't C, it's C++ (C doesn't have explicit references). This is an XY problem. Why are you trying to create a heterogeneous list of arguments? What is the _actual_ definition of `doStuff`?

Comment: Yes you are correct there aren't references in C(don't know why i used them instead of pointers in the example). In any way, it doesn't really matter what doStuff does, the point is that i must pass unknown number of constant arguments to it that pass certain conditions.

Comment: Quote: "Naturally this wont work, because va_list can't be used like this(used it only to roughly 'visualize' what is needed)". I mean... does va_list have "add" functionality? - no.

Comment: It stops me that if i have n=5 i must end up with doStuff(S, "Hello", 6, "Hello", 6, "Hello"), if i have n=6, it must have 1 more 6, etc.

Comment: If the types are manageable (small enough to make a case for each) but the number of each type is not, you could use arrays for each type and use n as the length of each array.

Comment: The number of arguments is set - n. The types of arguments don't really matter. But even so n can go up to 200 in the system i work in. That is 200 cases, is there no other workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C does not define any mechanism for constructing variable argument lists dynamically.  Normally, the compiler converts varargs calls to ordinary function calls, using implementation-specific mechanisms to handle the argument list on both sides of the call.  To do that, the compiler needs to know what the actual arguments to each call are.

If everything must ultimately go through the varargs function, then all your options are variations on either writing multiple alternative function calls and selecting dynamically which one to execute, or performing the work via several function calls.  It might be possible to combine those.

Consider, however, whether an appropriate part of the behavior of the varargs function can be factored out so that it can be exercised directly.  You might then, say, provide one or more alternative front ends that accept the data to use in the form of an array of structs instead of variable arguments.